# XCode 8.3.1 Error Mocking template class

Tags: c++, xcode, templates, googlemock

Given a template class like:

```
template<typename T,typename V>
class IAmTemplate {
public:
    virtual boost::shared_ptr<V> get_v() const = 0;
    virtual boost::shared_ptr<T> get_t() const = 0;
};
```

and a Mock implementation:

```
template <typename T, typename V>
class MockIAmTemplate : public IAmTemplate<T,V> {
public:
    MOCK_CONST_METHOD0_T(get_v, boost::shared_ptr<V>());
    MOCK_CONST_METHOD0_T(get_t, boost::shared_ptr<T>());
};
```

It seems like this should build without issues. And, indeed, I find that I can build this with clang, and DevStudio, and XCode 8.2. However when I move to XCode 8.3 or 8.3.1 I get errors thrown:
    .cache/cmake_build_system/ExternalLibs/gmock/v1.7.0_2/Applications_macosx_fat_cxx11/include/gmock/internal/gmock-internal-utils.h:371:7: Binding dereferenced null pointer to reference has undefined behavior

It seems like the MOCK macro is unhappy about the return type boost::shared_ptr, whereas in previous versions it was fine with it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, there's a more recent version of GMock, which fixes my problem. After switching my build to it, I no longer get the compile errors.